# Facebook Login Window Not close after Successfull login

Tags: facebook

I have implemented Facebook Connect with ASP.Net 3.5. My problem is when i click on Face book login the small window will open. when i pass the valid credential it will redirected to URL which i specified in Connect URL in Facebook application on developer.facebook.com. The main problem is this page is redirected on same page (small login page). not in new page. I want that if user logged in then that login window will be closed and main window will be redirected to url

Is there anything i missing in Facebook application setting?

is there anything missing in library or in javascript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the same question of this post: [Facebook Connect Dialog Box doesn't close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832867/facebook-connect-dialog-box-doesnt-close)

Comment: The question you're referring to addresses non-closing window when the login dialog is configured specifically using FBML.  This same issue could arise from a few different causes.
@Vivek are you using fbml like this '<fb:login-button size="large" onlogin="window.location.reload();">' to configure your login dialog?  If not how are you configuring your login dialog on the client?