# Facebook Connect Dialog Box doesn't close

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to use Facebook Connect on my website (which mostly uses ASP.NET). When the user clicks on the "Connect" Button, the "Connect URL" in Application Settings opens within the Connect Dialog itself.
How can I make the target URL open in the page with the "Connect" button?

My button is :

```
<fb:login-button size="large" onlogin="window.location.reload();">
```

Please do check out what exactly I'm saying at http://www.stockmadness.logicbomb.in (single page website)

Thanks.

Comment: Well, looks like you'll have to remove it from developer mode for anyone to test it: "Stock Madness (LogicBomb.in) is under construction. Please try again later."

Comment: It's not in Sandbox Mode. I had left the Connect URL empty. Check it out now. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

In this way it works for me:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="document.location.href=document.location.href;">
</fb:login-button>
```

It closes also if you remove the onlogin attribute (it's the default behaviour).
It seems that the code you pass in the onlogin attribute is a subset of javascript, is it possible?

I wrote a facebook connect tutorial [here](http://www.barattalo.it/facebook-connect-tutorial/). :-)

Comment: Pons, is this still relevant for OAuth 2.0?